# Relaciones entre Modelos Django

Tags: base-de-datos, django, django-models

Tengo dos modelos (Team y Player) y por lo que tengo entendido para esta situación lo mejor que puedo usar es el campo ForeignKey.
Esto funciona y me permite ver a que equipo pertenece cada jugador desde el panel de Admin de Django.
Pero no puedo ver los jugadores de cada equipo, y me preguntaba si esto sería posible.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="Enter the team name")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname

Soy completamente nuevo en esto y agradeceria cualquier tipo de ayuda, un saludo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Si claro, solo tienes que poner el parametro `related_name='nombre'`

ejemplo:

```py
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="Enter the team name")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,
    related_name='child_player' )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname
```

1. Ahora solo tienes que consultar el child_team en el modelo Team.  Ejemplo.

```py
>>> Team_player = Team.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> List_player = Team_player.child_player.filter()
```

2. Aqui consulto la lista de Team de un Modelo player

```py
>>> Get_Player = Player.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> List_Team = Get_Player.team.filter()
```

3. Este ultimo es como el primer ejemplo, pero se filtra segun su **nicname** y su **ID**

```py
>>> List_player = Team.child_player.filter(nickname='Juan')
>>> List_player2 = Team.child_player.filter(pk=1)
```